# Use Kotlin/Native prebuilt shared library from an Android application using JNI

Tags: android, jvm, java-native-interface, kotlin-native

I'm trying to build a Kotlin/Native library and use it in an Android application. I actually want to use a prebuilt shared library and not a .jar because I want my code to be obfuscated.

I've managed to make my Kotlin/Native library work in my Android application using JNI and a lot of trial and error. The thing is I've only made a very simple "Hello world" function work with this Kotlin/Native code:

```kotlin
fun sayHello(): String {
    return "Hello, Kotlin/Native!"
}
```

This C++ code for JNI:

```cpp
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_my_package_NativeLib_sayHello(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    libshared_lib_ExportedSymbols *lib = libshared_lib_symbols();
    return env->NewStringUTF(lib->kotlin.root.sayHello());
}
```

And finally this Kotlin code in my Android classes:

```kotlin
class NativeLib {
    external fun sayHello(): String

    companion object {
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("native-lib")
        }
    }
}
```

For the record, I'm building the Kotlin/Native with Gradle into a prebuilt shared library for android target. I then copy/paste the `.so` file in my app's libs folder, and with some Gradle magic I'm getting it to work.

However it gets more complicated when I start writing a function taking a ByteArray as a parameter like so (the implementation isn't relevant):

```kotlin
fun readByteArray(byteArray: ByteArray): String {
    val unsignedByteArray = byteArray.toUByteArray()
    var i = 0

    while (i < byteArray.size) {
        // Access the array
        val byte = unsignedByteArray[i].toUInt()
    }

    return "Done reading the array"
}
```

Then adding this to my `NativeLib` class on Android side:

```kotlin
external fun readByteArray(byteArray: ByteArray): String
```

And what should be the JNI C++ equivalent:

```cpp
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_my_package_NativeLib_readByteArray(JNIEnv *env, jobject,
                                            jbyteArray byte_array) {
    libshared_lib_ExportedSymbols *lib = libshared_lib_symbols();
    // What to do here?
    return env->NewStringUTF(lib->kotlin.root.readByteArray(/* and here? */));
}
```

The thing is Kotlin/Native is generating this header file:

```c
typedef void* libshared_lib_KNativePtr;
...
typedef struct {
  libshared_lib_KNativePtr pinned;
} libshared_lib_kref_kotlin_Byte;
...
typedef struct {
  libshared_lib_KNativePtr pinned;
} libshared_lib_kref_kotlin_ByteArray;
...
struct {
  struct {
    const char* (*readByteArray)(libshared_lib_kref_kotlin_ByteArray byteArray);
    const char* (*sayHello)();
  } root;
} kotlin;
...
```

That's where I get stuck, how exactly should I build a `libshared_lib_kref_kotlin_ByteArray`? Here's what I've tried so far, only to get a crash when the code tries to read the array:

```cpp
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_my_package_NativeLib_readByteArray(JNIEnv *env, jobject,
                                            jbyteArray byte_array) {
    libshared_lib_ExportedSymbols *lib = libshared_lib_symbols();
    libshared_lib_KNativePtr ptr = env->GetDirectBufferAddress(byte_array);
    libshared_lib_kref_kotlin_ByteArray byteArray;
    byteArray.pinned = ptr;
    return env->NewStringUTF(lib->kotlin.root.readByteArray(byteArray));
}
```

I also tried using `GetByteArrayElements()` without success.
Does anyone know how to proceed with those Kotlin generated types?

Comment: Despite having the same name, your Kotlin/Native ByteArray has nothing to do with Java's `byte[]` or the `char*` you wrangled from JNIEnv.

Comment: From what little I was able to find, you want your Kotlin/native function (here `readByteArray`) to take a `CPointer<Byte>` and a length.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm looking into it. Looks like I'd need a `CPointer<ByteVar>` to be exact. I'm still trying to figure out the JNI part though, to call my K/N function from the C with a jbyteArray

Comment: For that you want GetByteArrayElements to get a pointer.

Comment: Yay, you're right, just got it working using this in JNI: `jbyte *nativeByteArray = env->GetByteArrayElements(byte_array, nullptr);` followed by `const char *response = lib->kotlin.root.readByteArray(nativeByteArray, len);`.
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I suggest you create a self-answer for other people who stumble across this problem. That way they can find your post and the solution more easily.

Comment: I'll do that, I was gonna ask if you wanted to write an answer that I could mark as the accepted one. But I guess it's easier if I do it so I can write the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Botje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1548468/botje) stated in the comments of my question, it looks like I needed to use C interop types in my Kotlin/Native function for it to be called correctly from the JNI C code.

So here's the Kotlin/Native code I had to write:

```kotlin
fun readByteArray(byteArray: CPointer<ByteVar>, length: Int): String {
    // Convert the C interop array type to a standard Kotlin type
    val ktByteArray = byteArray.readBytes(length)

    // Here access the `ktByteArray` as we would any Kotlin array

    return "Done reading the array"
}
```

And here's the C++ JNI glue to tie it with my Kotlin JVM code:

```cpp
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_my_package_NativeLib_readByteArray(JNIEnv *env, jobject,
                                            jbyteArray byte_array) {
    libshared_lib_ExportedSymbols *lib = libshared_lib_symbols();
    jsize len = env->GetArrayLength(byte_array);
    jbyte *nativeByteArray = env->GetByteArrayElements(byte_array, nullptr);
    const char *response = lib->kotlin.root.readByteArray(nativeByteArray, len);
    return env->NewStringUTF(response);
}
```